# How can I split a sentence based on underscore in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am currently dealing with text processing and get distracted by a simple problem. I tried to split the sentence based on an underscore. Firstly, I came up with a very simple approach:

```
String[] tokens = taggedSentence.split("_");
```

It works fine for most cases until I found the text that was written like:

```
Robert_Phd_NNP
```

However, i am only interested with the POS tag, which is in this case is NNP, but it seems splitting with underscore alone is not enough. Then, I came up with an idea to get the last element of the split sentence:

```
String[] tokens = taggedSentence.split("_");
int tokenSize = tokens.length;
String pos = tokens[tokenSize-1];
```

However, I wonder if there is a better way (like regex, maybe) to do this. Any comment or suggestion would be really appreciated.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily without regular expressions:

```
String POStag = taggedSentence.substring(taggedSentence.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
```

If there is no underscore, this will just return the original string.

Comment: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.` Nice answer.

Comment: cool.. It is obviously much simpler than mine. I am so newbie :D thanks :)

Comment: @Jashaszun ya, you are right. Regex was the first thing that came up to my mind when I faced this case. Thanks to Sean Bright